# iOS 9 How to trigger an action after UINavigationController has resized after keyboard disappears

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a UISplitViewController with a UINavigationController as the mater view. When the keyboard retracts, after closing an alert with a textfield, the animation seems to be the keyboard fully retracts, then the master view resizes as a visible two step process. The first image shows the keyboard hidden while the master view is resizing.

[Screen shot showing resizing master view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISNwk.jpg)

I want to pop an action sheet automatically to prompt the user for the next step. I can wait for the UIKeyboardDidHide event, but the master view has not resized so the action sheet ends popping in the middle of the screen.

[Screen shot showing floating action sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gha8F.jpg)

Is there a way to know when the animation is finished, so that I know when to pop the action sheet in the correct position?

Alternatively, is there a way to keep the master view from resizing to put the toolbar above the keyboard?